# Rails Preloading is not working with polymorphic relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems, polymorphism

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :photos, -> { order(main: :desc, id: :asc) }, as: :photoable, class_name: 'Photo', dependent: :destroy
```

---

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :photoable, polymorphic: true
```

---

```
projects = Project.limit(10).includes(:photos)

SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."is_deleted" = $1 LIMIT 10  [["is_deleted", "f"]]
Photo Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."photoable_type" = 'Project' AND "photos"."photoable_id" IN (1, 403, 371, 8784, 12, 34, 11, 1111, 31, 22)  ORDER BY "photos"."main" DESC, "photos"."id" ASC
```

---

```
 projects.first.photo
 Photo Load (0.6ms)
```

It is sending a DB query which gets executed in (0.6ms). Any idea how i can avoid a DB query ?

I'm using Rails 4.2.6 & Ruby 2.3.1p112

Answer (score 0):

```
projects = Project.includes(:photos).limit(10)
```

Then iterate through the projects. It wont trigger another query.

```
projects.each do |project|
  project.photo
end
```